# How to configure PuLP to call GLPK solver

Tags: python, pulp, glpk

I am using the PuLP library in Python to solve an MILP problem. I have run my problem successfully with the default solver (CBC). Now I would like to use PuLP with another solver (GLPK). **How do I set up PuLP with GLPK?**

I have done some research online and found information on how to use GLPK (e.g. with `lp_prob.solve(pulp.GLPK_CMD())`) but haven't found information on how to actually set up PuLP with GLPK (or any other solver for that matter), so that it finds my GLPK installation. I have already installed GLPK seperately (but I didn't add it to my PATH environment variable).

I ran the command `pulp.pulpTestAll()`

and got:

`Solver <class 'pulp.solvers.GLPK_CMD'> unavailable`

I know that I should be getting a "passed" instead of an "unavailable" to be able to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading in more detail the code and testing out some things, I finally found out how to use GLPK with PuLP, without changing anything in the PuLP package itself.

Your need to pass the path as an argument to GLPK_CMD in solve as follows (replace with your *glpsol* path):

`lp_prob.solve(GLPK_CMD(path = 'C:\\Users\\username\\glpk-4.65\\w64\\glpsol.exe')`

You can also pass options that way, e.g.

`lp_prob.solve(GLPK_CMD(path = 'C:\\Users\\username\\glpk-4.65\\w64\\glpsol.exe', options = ["--mipgap", "0.01","--tmlim", "1000"])`

Comment: I did that but it says `PulpSolverError: PuLP: cannot execute C:\Program Files\glpk-4.65\w64\glpsol.exe`

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, but is not related with glpk installation, is with solution file create, the message is confusim. My problem was I use numeric name for my variables, as '0238' ou '1342', I add a 'x' before it, then they looked like 'x0238'.